# Do I need manage_page permission to manage my page using facebook php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I created a facebook app in order to use it as a login for my website.
I wish to use this app to get my page likes count, and offline post to this page.
I'm the admin of both the page and the application.
I don't want to take any actions with my users pages. only my page.
do I still need the manage_page permission?

this is the code i'm trying using the app token that I am getting from the graph API explorer

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '1111111111111111111111',
            'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
        ]);

        try {
              // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
              $response = $fb->get(
                '/252525x25252x525252x5252525/likes',
                'apptokenapptokenapptokenapptoken'
              );
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }
            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();


                 var_dump($graphNode);
```

but i'm getting this error:

> Graph returned an error: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access',
>   your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook.
>   To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please
>   read our documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

When I tried to get page access token from graph api explorer using a different browser on mobile phone I get this,

[image: ee]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to authorize with the `manage_pages` permission, and you have to use a Page Token of the page in question to get data. With the App Token, you would need to get `Page Public Content Access` approved.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: why the downvote? i am happy to update my answer if something is wrong, but i know that it is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure. But anyway I updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: that´s weird, the permission definitely exists. i would file a bug at facebook.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to just access *your* page, you can do it without going through app review. Users with developer access to the app bypass (most of) app review.

Your issue is here:

```
apptokenapptokenapptokenapptoken
```

This exemption does **not** apply to access via an app-level token. Use a [Page-level access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens) acquired from a user of the app with developer privileges. (This is pretty easily done via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ - just click "Get Token" and then "Get Page Access Token".)

Comment: I am trying to get "page access token" from the API explorer. but I get a popup with the following message: "Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later." but I'm the admin user of the application. and i am already logged in.

Comment: @medoampir You won't be able to go through the OAuth flow to get the bypassed-privileges token. You should be able to get it from the Graph API explorer I linked.

Comment: Hmm, odd. They've gone and changed something, then. Very Facebooky of them. I'll bet it only works if the app is in development mode now. Try creating a "test app" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/), keeping it in development mode and using it to do this part of your project.